# Excel Range less clumsy

Tags: excel, vba

As an old dog (age 73) learning new (Excel VBA) tricks, I am reasonably happy with putting together the code below. But I think it could be cleaner. How would you have coded it?

```
Dim thisDate As Double  'start timestamp
thisDate = Now()
With Sheets("Pressure Log")
    lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row     'populate next row with date/time
    .Range("B" & lastRow + 1 & ":G" & lastRow + 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1) = Format(thisDate, "dddd")
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 1) = Format(thisDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 2) = Format(thisDate, "hh:mm AM/PM")
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 3).Select 'position for data    
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The `End(xlUp)` mostly works, but write a value in the last cell in column `B` and try it, in this case it will probably not return the last row. Also in the case when the `lastRow` would be the last row on the sheet, the code `& ":G" & lastRow + 1).Borders...` will fail.

Comment: Thank you dee. In fact I had the problem you describe, but did not know how to get around it (so I instantiated a new workbook). I considered iterating a check of each row until I found a blank one, but that seems clumsy too. How would you handle it?

Comment: Instead of `End(xlUp)` the `Find` can be used, have a look e.g. [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/). In your case where you want to find the last cell with value in particular column it would 
 be something like this: `Dim r As Long
Dim last As Range
    
    Set last = Sheets("Pressure Log").Range("B1").EntireColumn.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    
    If (last Is Nothing) Then r = 1 Else r = last.Row`

Comment: I see I have some study time ahead of me, dee. Thanks. I certainly would not have figured that out on my own.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think questions of this nature are meant for CodeReview. You may get a better response there.

I'm not sure my version is necessarily better:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddCurrentDateTimeAfterLastRow()
    Dim thisDate As Double
    thisDate = Now()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pressure Log")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim outputArray() As Variant
        ReDim outputArray(1 To 3)

        outputArray(1) = Format(thisDate, "dddd")
        outputArray(2) = Format(thisDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        outputArray(3) = Format(thisDate, "hh:mm AM/PM")

        With .Cells(lastRow + 1, "B").Resize(1, UBound(outputArray))
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .FormulaLocal = outputArray
            .Parent.Parent.Activate
            .Parent.Activate
            .Cells(1, 3).Select
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

- Put `Option Explicit` before your code to ensure all variables are declared. (Maybe you already had this, I don't know. The beginning of your code seems to be missing.)
- Qualify the workbook (e.g. `Thisworkbook` or `Set` a reference to it), otherwise it will be assumed to be whichever one is active at the time of code execution.
- My understanding is `Sheets` can refer to regular worksheets and chart sheets, whereas `Worksheets` can only refer to worksheets. So it might be good to be explicit and just use `Worksheets`.
- Since you want the macro (at the end) to select the cell, it's important that the worksheet and the workbook (which contain the cell) are active at the time of selection. Otherwise, you risk getting an error.
- I put your day, date, time into an array, then wrote said array to the worksheet. I just thought the array element assignments were shorter and cleaner (to read and maintain).

Comment: Exactly the type of response I was hoping for. Your explanations are especially valuable. Thank you chillin

Comment: I guess it's a bit misleading to store date in a Double variable, isn't it?

Comment: I used double because I thought the timestamp is the number of seconds since a date in 1970 or some such. Should I have used something else?

Comment: @grNadpa Using `Date` type would have been more appropriate. `Date` stores both the date and time component of a given date time/timestamp -- and represents the amount of time since `1 Jan 1900` or `1 Jan 1904` (depending on your settings). The reason why it's not totally wrong to use `Double` (and why the code worked with `thisDate` declared as `Double`), is that Excel internally stores/represents all dates as a decimal number (AKA a `Double`). So for the most part they're interchangeable (there are edge cases where this is not true, and this is due to how computers store floating points).

Comment: @grNadpa But in the code above, the amendment is as simple as replacing `Dim thisDate As Double` with `Dim thisDate As Date` -- and nothing else should subsequently break/need fixing.

Comment: @chillin I followed your suggestion and cross-posted to CodeReview. For whatever reason, they deleted my statement that it was a cross-post leaving only my original text.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Private Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Pressure Log"
' Or change sheet name in Properties window from Sheet1 to wksPressureLog,
' otherwise any sheet renaming will result in code crash
'
' Another optimization - is to assign column positions to constants
' for example column B here is used 3 times, if you'll decide to modify
' table - you'll have to find and change all these 3 instances, and in big 
' scripts it will be hard enough to understand what each number means

' Execute only once
Sub FormatColumns()
    With Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
        .Cells(1, 2).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dddd"
        .Cells(1, 3).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .Cells(1, 4).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub

Sub InsertData()
    With Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
        With .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
            .Resize(1, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Resize(1, 3) = Now()
            .Offset(0, 3).Select 'position for data
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Konstantin. I see you split this into two modules. Is this for encapsulation? I gather I would need another module to call these. (Currently I embed my code in Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Comment: Each iteration with worksheet uses resources, that's why I've decided to separate action that should be executed before every entry and cell formatting which you can run once (you can even format columns manually).
You can leave these procedure in the same module (by the way they are using Private Const SHEET_NAME, which is visible within the module only), and you can assign 2 buttons to these procedures.

Comment: Ahh-h-h. I understand. Thank you